# SQL Query two values for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to query a customers table to get the total number of accounts per rep grouped by whether they were created this year or before.

- CUSTOMER NAME
- ACCOUNT REP
- DATE CREATED

The query I'm trying to return would look like.

```
REP | NEW_ACCOUNTS | OLD_ACCOUNTS | TOTAL
-----------------------------------------
Tom | 100          | 12           | 112
Ted | 15           | 1            | 16
```

The query I've written looks as follows.

```
SELECT        REP, CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) > YEAR(DATE_CREATED) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ThisYear
FROM          CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY      REP, DATE_CREATED
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me

```
REP | ThisYear
-----------------------------------------
Tom | 1
Ted | 0
Tom | 0
Ted | 1
Ted | 1
```

Comment: You are close try Using `Count()` with current query for ex. `SUM(CASE WHEN .....<your condition> as NEW_ACCOUNTS), SUM(CASE WHEN ....<condition flip for old records> as OLD_ACCOUNTS` that should do it.

Comment: Did you try DISTINCT in your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT REP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) = YEAR(DATE_CREATED) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NEW_ACCOUNTS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) > YEAR(DATE_CREATED) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OLD_ACCOUNTS,
       COUNT(*) as TOTAL
FROM CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY REP;
```

This assumes that creation dates are not in the future -- a reasonable assumption.

If you want one row per `REP`, then the only column in the `GROUP BY` should be `REP`.

Answer (score 1):

You can want conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT REP, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) = YEAR(DATE_CREATED) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NEW_ACCOUNTS,            
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) > YEAR(DATE_CREATED) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OLD_ACCOUNTS, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL       
FROM CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY REP;
```

Comment: use this condition YEAR(GETDATE()) > YEAR(DATE_CREATED), If use '<' it gives 0 result